# testing random pages for uptime (part of an SLA)

Tags: performance, tools, load-time

We have outsourced hosting of a large website.

We have an SLA for response times of random pages. I.e. every minute a random page will be chosen from a pool of 30,000 pages and its response time recorded.

I know about Monitis, Pingdom, etc., but to my knowledge none of these services allow for the selection of random pages.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a good tool for automated testing. You'll need to give it a list of random pages. You could construct this by putting a list of all 30,000 pages into an Excel spreadsheet, add another column containing the formulua `=RAND()` and then sorting by that column.

To measure response times you could use the [Selenium timer extension](http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.com/2010/12/selenium-timer-extension.html).

Comment: Thanks for this. Could I use Selenium to repeatedly run the test of a random page? I'm looking for something to run 24/7/365.  Probably possible to integrate with Jenkins-CI, but it feels like abusing a Continuous Integration tool for monitoring, or am I being over sensitive?

Comment: Yes, you can run Selenium repeatedly. I don't suppose Jenkins will mind!